# Windows Command to get all information/properties of a file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Is there any command get all the properties of a file including its encoding format (this piece of information is really important to me) on Windows ? I'm looking for something similar to stat in Linux

I'd prefer using a command that can be used in command-prompt or a batch script although I know its possible with Powershell.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows Server 2008/ Windows 7 onwards

Answer (score 15):

You can use WMIC feature to do that.

For example :

```
F:>> wmic datafile where Name="anyfile.txt"
```

to get all information about anyfile.txt. You can use CMD and powershell too to using WMIC. And you can use GET parameter to get a specified information.

For Example:

```
F:>> wmic datafile where Name="F:\\ekojs.txt" get Description,Path,Status,Version
```

**EDIT :**
Try using this before to check the WMIC functionality :

```
F:>> wmic datafile /?
```

To get a help how to using it.

Command :

```
wmic datafile where Name="F:\\ekojs.txt" get Description,Name,FileType >> eko_wmic.txt
```

Output in eko_wmic.txt:

```
Description   FileType       Name          
f:\ekojs.txt  Text Document  f:\ekojs.txt
```

Hope this'll help you out..

Comment: I keep getting an error "No Instance(s) Available"

Comment: you run this command using cmd ? or powershell ?

Comment: Sorry I've mistake command at first answer. but I've edited it. hope it run well.

Comment: I used "cmd" with Administrative Privileges. wmic datafile /? didn't help :( Can you please edit your answer and give me  the exact query you used to get information of some file with the ouput as well. ?

Comment: Check my edited answer...

Comment: btw, what's wrong with your error using that command ? keep getting an error "No Instance(s) Available" ?

Comment: Yes what is the meaning of "No Instance(s) Available" ?If I just type 
"wmic" it takes me to the following location- wmic:root\cli>wmic

Comment: Yes you can do that, you get in to `wmic` and type after `wmic:root\cli>` and do the command in my answer. About `No Instance(s)` you can try to fix that using powershell and type :`Get-HotFix`

Comment: Any `extra spaces` or you get your code using `copy/paste` may come in to error `No Instance(s)` :)

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam - I am getting this `"No Instance(s) Available"` error with command `wmic datafile where name="file.txt" get creationdate`. I opened Powershell and typed: `Get-HotFix`. It returns a list of all HotFixes (updates, service packs, security updates...) **that have already been installed**. Is there a specific "KB" numbered HotFix that I need?

Comment: From [Dale C](https://superuser.com/users/863386/dale-c): The linked response, https://superuser.com/questions/1024034/no-instances-available-error-with-the-wmic-command,  has the resolution to “No Instance(s) Available” where the full escaped file path to for the file name has to be used.

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar: I ran into the  "No Instance(s) Available" error too. I silved it by escaping all backslashes with an extra \.

Comment: wmic works for me, but results are unreadable - its a mixture of headers and some values. Is there any way to suggest wmic to use newlines at some point?

Comment: I have read rest of your answer and I use `get` with specified values.

Comment: After fixing the No instances available error by executing `powershell` and then `Get-Hotfix`, I got an `Invalid query` error which I fixed with `--%` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130226/error-description-invalid-query

Ultimately something like: `wmic --% datafile where Name="C:\\Users\\me\\somefile.txt" get Path`

Answer (score 5):

To build on the previous answer.  You can use `wmic datafile` to get info about a file, but you have to provide the full path **and double-up your slashes like so**

```
wmic datafile where Name="F:\\anyfile.txt"
```

This gives an unreadable mess in the console, as you'll see:

[image: what a great way to render data, wmic]

However if you pipe this into a text file, it's pretty legible

```
wmic datafile where Name="F:\\anyfile.txt" >> fileprops.txt
```

[image]

Fortunately, `wmic` can format the info as a list, and then it is actually pretty useful.

```
wmic datafile where Name="F:\\anyfile.txt" list /format:list
```

[image]

You can then provide these properties only for a simplified view, *note that you must remove the `list` keyword*.

```
>wmic datafile where Name="G:\\ipcamera.log" get Hidden,FileSize,Name  /format:list


FileSize=20
Hidden=FALSE
Name=G:\ipcamera.log
```

A little piece of trivia, wmic was the foundation for what eventually became PowerShell!

Comment: The wmic list display is quite useful; I used to use that same command but without the list part. For info on folders/directories, use `wmic FSDIR where Name="C:\\path\\to\\folder" list /format:list`. Online docs: https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use any scripting language that can use COM objects such as vbscript and powershell to access a files extended properties (Title, Duration, Frame rate, etc.) using the Shell.Application object. Unfortunately, cmd does not have a direct way to access the Shell object, you will have to piggyback on some other scripting language to access the Shell object.

Running the following command from a cmd prompt window will display the duration of the video file in 100ns units (not milliseconds).

```
PowerShell -Command "$FilePath='C:\Videos\Test.mp4'; Write-Host ((New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Split-Path -Parent -Path $FilePath))).ParseName((Split-Path -Leaf -Path $FilePath)).ExtendedProperty('System.Media.Duration')"
```

Additional information about the command can be found at [Enumerate file properties in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420055/enumerate-file-properties-in-powershell/65974111#65974111)

Answer (score 0):

Just spend two days on trying to write the rating used in the  Windows File Explorer through scripting or command line.
Reading was easy enough, see the other answers, writing was another matter.
Finally found a tool that has a GUI but can also be used from the command line.
[PropertySystemView from Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_property_system_view.html)

Example: set the rating of an mp4 to the lowest value

```
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "d:\test.mp4" "System.Rating" 1
```

Some other examples:

```
Export the list of all properties of 1.mp4 file into csv file
PropertySystemView.exe /Filename "c:\temp\1.mp4" /scomma "c:\temp\mp4_properties.csv"
Export the list of all properties on your system into html5 file
PropertySystemView.exe /AllProperties /shtml "c:\temp\all_system_properties.html"
Set the 'Media Created' date/time of single .mp4 file.
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\temp\1.mp4" "System.Media.DateEncoded" "2018/11/23:08:10:30.000"
Set the 'Media Created' date/time of all .mp4 files on c:\myfiles folder
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\myfiles\*.mp4" "System.Media.DateEncoded" "2015/10/15:00:00:00.000"
Copy the value of System.DateCreated property into the System.Media.DateEncoded property
PropertySystemView.exe /CopyProperty "C:\temp\1.mp4" System.DateCreated System.Media.DateEncoded
Remove the comment from all .mp4 files on c:\myfiles folder
PropertySystemView.exe /RemoveProperty "c:\myfiles\*.mp4" "System.Comment"
Set the 'Date Taken' value of all .jpg files on c:\pictures folder
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\pictures\*.jpg" "System.Photo.DateTaken" "2019/11/01:10:00:00.000"
Set the last saved date of the specified Excel file:
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\temp\myfile.xlsx" "System.Document.DateSaved" "2019/10/20:11:22:33.000"
Set the 'Content Created' date/time of the specified Excel file:
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\temp\myfile.xlsx" "System.Document.DateCreated" "2019/01/31:22:59:50.000"
Set the authors of all Excel files on c:\myfiles folder:
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\myfiles\*.xlsx" "System.Author" "NirSoft"
Set the 'Last Saved By' value of all Excel files on c:\myfiles folder:
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\myfiles\*.xlsx" "System.Document.LastAuthor" "NirSoft"
Set the title of Excel file:
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\myfiles\1.xlsx" "System.Title" "This is my Excel file"
Set the 'Last Saved By' value of MS-Word file:
PropertySystemView.exe /SetProperty "c:\myfiles\mydoc.docx" "System.Document.LastAuthor" "NirSoft"
Set the System.AppUserModel.ID property of a window that its handle is 010C0A35 to MyWindow
PropertySystemView.exe /SetPropertyWindow 010C0A35 "System.AppUserModel.ID" "MyWindow"
Open the location of the specified .jpg file in Google Maps:
PropertySystemView.exe /Filename "C:\temp\20200719_090250.jpg" /OpenGoogleMaps
```