# "No Instance(s) Available" error with the wmic command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, wmic

I'm getting a "No Instance(s) Available" error with the wmic command. The command I'm running (from an elevated/administrator cmd.exe window) is:

```
G:\>wmic datafile where name="file.txt" get creationdate
No Instance(s) Available
```

The file "file.txt" does exist.

I have found some mention of this problem in other SU questions/answers like the answer here:

[Windows Command to get all information/properties of a file](https://superuser.com/questions/898017/windows-command-to-get-all-information-properties-of-a-file)

but I have not found any mention of how to fix (or even troubleshoot) this problem.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium x64.

---

When I run "wmic datafile /?" I get usage syntax help:

```
G:\>wmic datafile /?

DATAFILE - DataFile Management.

HINT: BNF for Alias usage.
(<alias> [WMIObject] | <alias> [<path where>] | [<alias>] <path where>) [<verb clause>].

USAGE:

DATAFILE ASSOC [<format specifier>]
DATAFILE CALL <method name> [<actual param list>]
DATAFILE CREATE <assign list>
DATAFILE DELETE
DATAFILE GET [<property list>] [<get switches>]
DATAFILE LIST [<list format>] [<list switches>]
```

Comment: What is the output on `wmic datafile /?`  Does [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2703061) apply to your described file?

Comment: @Ramhound - That article talks about "Windows Server 2008 R2 configured with failover clustering". I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium x64, so although it is the same error message, I don't think it applies to me. The file is on a partition on my desktop hard drive. It happens with any file I have tried, even something like `C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"`

Comment: @KevinFegan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054.aspx: You may use string literals, such as "NTFS", in a WHERE clause. If you wish to include the following special characters in your string, you must first escape the character by prefixing the character with a backslash (\\):

    backslash (\\\)
    double quotes (\")
    single quotes (\')

Comment: @KevinFegan See my answer. You need to escape a single backslash \ and use \\ instead (as well as use drive and path)

Comment: @KevinFegan See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758713%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for some examples ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I'm getting a "No Instance(s) Available" error with the following wmic command.

```
G:\>wmic datafile where name="file.txt" get creationdate
```

You need to provide the full name (including the drive and path) of the file.

Example:

```
F:\test>wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe" get CreationDate
CreationDate
20090714005636.838522+060
```

Note the use of `\\` to escape a single `\` in the above example name string.

---

> If you wish to include the following special characters in your
>   string, you must first escape the character by prefixing the character
>   with a backslash (\):
>
> - backslash (\\)
> - double quotes (\")
> - single quotes (\')

Source [WHERE Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054.aspx)

---

#### What are the valid keywords (name, path, ...) for the where clause with datafile?

You can get the property list from the command line using:

```
wmic datafile get /?
```

Any of the property names can be used in a where clause.

```
F:\test>wmic datafile get /?

Property get operations.
USAGE:

GET [<property list>] [<get switches>]
NOTE: <property list> ::= <property name> | <property name>,  <property list>

The following properties are available:
Property                                Type                    Operation
========                                ====                    =========
Access Rights                           N/A                     N/A
Caption                                 N/A                     N/A
Class Name                              N/A                     N/A
Compressed                              N/A                     N/A
Compression Method                      N/A                     N/A
Computer System Class Name              N/A                     N/A
Computer System Name                    N/A                     N/A
Creation Date                           N/A                     N/A
Current File Open Count                 N/A                     N/A
Description                             N/A                     N/A
Drive                                   N/A                     N/A
Eight Dot Three File Name               N/A                     N/A
Encrypted                               N/A                     N/A
Encryption Method                       N/A                     N/A
File Extension                          N/A                     N/A
File Name                               N/A                     N/A
File System Class Name                  N/A                     N/A
File System Name                        N/A                     N/A
File Type                               N/A                     N/A
Hidden                                  N/A                     N/A
Install Date                            N/A                     N/A
Last Accessed                           N/A                     N/A
Last Modified                           N/A                     N/A
Manufacturer                            N/A                     N/A
Name                                    N/A                     N/A
Path                                    N/A                     N/A
Readable                                N/A                     N/A
Should Be Archived                      N/A                     N/A
Size                                    N/A                     N/A
Status                                  N/A                     N/A
System File                             N/A                     N/A
Version                                 N/A                     N/A
Writeable                               N/A                     N/A
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [WMIC Best practices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758713%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [WHERE Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054.aspx)

Comment: This is more or less where my thought was going with my link

Comment: I tried `wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe" get CreationDate` (and even `wmic datafile where name="C:notepad.exe" get CreationDate`) and well... they work ! (you knew they would). I am sure I tried that before when it was failing, but I probably had something else wrong with the command syntax at the time. Thanks for your help. Do you have a link to info about valid keywords (name, path, ...) for the WHERE clause with DATAFILE?

Comment: @KevinFegan No link, but you can get the property list from the command line using `wmic datafile get /?`. Any property name can be used in a `where` clause as I understand it.

Comment: *... `wmic datafile get /?`*  That was it. Thanks again. I was trying `wmic datafile where /?`, which doesn't return anything very useful.