How to make file information (from the "details" section) copyable?
When checking the "General" tab of the properties of a file, one can select and copy the corresponding information, as you can see in this example:

After pressing CtrlC, opening Notepad and pressing CtrlV, this is what I see in notepad:

In other words, the information in the "general" tab of the file properties is copyable.
This seems not to be true for the "Details" tab, as you can see:

Pressing CtrlC, re-opening Notepad and pressing CtrlV, gives the following result:

=> indeed, nothing has changed, and having a look at the clipboard viewer (WinV) confirmed my suspicion that the latter information from the "Details" tab has indeed not been copied into the clipboard.
I have seen with another employer how information can be added to the properties of a file, and I remember having copied that information to the clipboard.
Until now, I have only been able to add information to the properties of a compiled file in the "Details" tab, which makes that information "uncopyable".
As far as I can judge, it's impossible to add information to the "General" tab of the properties of a compiled file, so I wonder:
How can I make entries in the "Details" tab copyable?
Thanks in advance
Oh, by the way: I'm working with Windows-10. I might have seen the mentioned behaviour at a Windows-Server platform but I'm not sure about that anymore.

I believe you can use the wmic command, and pipe it into a .txt file, e.g.:
wmic datafile where Name="F:\\file.txt" >> props.txt
Related post:
Windows Command to get all information/properties of a file

Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/898017/windows-command-to-get-all-information-properties-of-a-file

No. I don't want to turn around the fact that it can't be done (copying file information, using a simple mouse select). I've seen it, I've done it and I want to do it at my current employer's system.

Well, to be fair, the above can also be bound to a mouse hotkey/key combination via AHK if desired.  You can compile it into a portable .exe for cross-PC interoperability.
